# Playing Saved Audio File with a Higher Pitch Android Studio

Tags: java, android, audio, android-studio, audio-recording

Hello is there a way to play a audio file saved on a android device with a higher pitch, and maybe save the high pitched recording

Comment: Try speeding it up by upping the sample rate? So-> playback at higher sample rate and record that playback buffer

Comment: Ok thank you, I used SoundPool, but it only works for sound 5 seconds or shorter.

Comment: did you find a way to do this?

Comment: I never completed the project, but I would recommend the java audio libaraies